# Salesforce Bulk API v2: Trying to upsert Tasks/Events but API can't find my custom external ID field

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

When I try to initiate a bulk upsert job of Events, I get this from the API:

`Upsert requires view all data on a non-unique custom index`

The field I'm trying to use as the `externalIdFieldName` exists on the Activity object and is defined as an External ID field so I'm not clear on what the problem is.

I've tried digging through the permission sets to figure out if the API client doesn't have access to the field, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: It's an external id, cool. But is it also marked unique?

Comment: that did it, thank you so much! when creating the extID field on other objects, that flag wasn't necessary but I should've known activity objects are a special case